# Make text to have background + border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I have a label with its content "White, Yellow, Black" and I want to make "yellow" to have a white background color + border with black line around the word "Yellow".

What XAML code is needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the content:

```
<Label>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="White, "/>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock Background="White" Text="Yellow"/>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Text=", Black"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Label>
```

(*If this is not what you want you should express yourself more clearly*)